# If condition range doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I am not able to make the code below to work when you copy-paste values in columns A, C and D. If for example I am in row2 and I insert data in cell A2, C2 and D2, the code does its job. But if I copy-paste data in row 3, 4, 5 the code doesn't check anymore the condition. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me to fix this matter. Thanks!

```
Sub LogicalPart(i As Long)

    If (Cells(i, "C") + Cells(i, "D")) <> Cells(i, "A") Then
        MsgBox "C" & i & " + D" & i & " must equal cell A" & i & " which is: " & Range("A" & i).Value
        MsgBox ("Please insert again the data in cell C" & i & " or D " & i & "!")
        Cells(i, "C").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Cells(i, "D").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Else
       Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "D")).Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
    End If

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C1:d10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
   LogicalPart Target.row
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: there's may be some issues with your code depending on how you enter data, but please explain the issue more clearly as it works for me as described in your problem statement. Also, have you debugged the code (stepped through line-by-line) to observe the actual behavior versus what is expected.

Comment: This will not work if you are changing more than one cell at a time.  You will need to iterate through the Target.rows

Comment: Yes, the code works if for example I am in row1 and insert the values in the following order: A1 = i.e. 12, C1 = i.e. 10 and D1 = i.e. 3. As C1+D1 is not equal A1 I will receive the error. However, if I copy-paste the values from A1, C1 and D1 and paste them in row2, row3 and row4, the error will show only in row2, but not in row3 and row4. I want them to show also in those rose. Thanks @Scott Holtzman

Comment: Might want to add a way to suppress the `Msgbox`s when its dealing with a multi-row change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate the rows in the target range:

```
Target.Row
```

Will only return the first row and not all of them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngrow As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Range("C1:d10"), Target)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each rngrow In rng.Rows
        LogicalPart rngrow.Row
    Next rngrow
End If


End Sub
```